# Box-sizing refuse to work properly

Tags: css

I have some simple html structure :

```
<section>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/db5df4870e4e4b6cbf42727fd434701a.jpg"/>
    <h4>Something here</h4>
  </a>
</section>
```

And i applied to the section a box-sizing:border-box; also I gave the ancor a hover state that increase the padding,something like :

```
section a:hover{
  padding:5px 0px;
}
```

But unespectly the section increase size.If i aply box sizing the padding should go inside and this thing doesn't happen.Can you take a look at my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Code_me/kDRp7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a fixed height on the section. Otherwise, there is no overflow; the section will grow to fit the content.